# PushApps for iOS - how to handle the push dictionary in my root view controller?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushapps

I want to handle the push notification dictionary in my root view controller (and not in my AppDelegate), but when using a NSNotification it does not work! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Working with **NSNotification** to pass the push notification dictionary, will work only when the app is already open. The reason for that is that the root view controller is not yet initialized, when the push notification is handled (at startup).
2. Implement PushApps [delegate](http://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/PushApps+Delegation#PushAppsDelegation-HandleNotifications) and specific that method
3. Inside this method, save the push notification dictionary to the **NSUserDefaults**.
4. Inside your root view controller **ViewWillAppear** method, take the parameters back from the **NSUserDeafults**
5. Do not forget to erase the dictionary from the **NSUserDefaults**, so that next time you won’t handle the same push notification again.